# Graphql codegen configuration does not load documents with Glob Expression

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-codegen

My API is written with TypeScript/Apollo and I am able to run queries/mutations on http://localhost:4000/graphql.
My front-end is with Next.js and Apollo client. I use GraphQL Codegenerator to generate the client-side code I need.

I am using:

```
"@graphql-codegen/cli": "1.20.1",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript": "1.20.2",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "1.17.14",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "2.2.1",
```

and my `codegen.yml` file is

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
documents: "src/graphql/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
```

The script I run when I change my API resolvers is `"gen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"`

If I do run this code, I get the error:

```
  ✖ src/generated/graphql.tsx
    Error: 
          Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers:
        
              - src/graphql/**/*.graphql
```

but If set my `codegen.yml` file as follows it works (and I tested a query in one of the component, I can access data):

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
documents:
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RecipeSnippet.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RegularError.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RegularUser.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RegularUserResponse.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/createRecipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/deleteRecipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/login.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/logout.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/register.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/updateRecipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/queries/me.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/queries/recipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/queries/recipes.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
```

I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong and what is even weirder is that it used to work. I remember updating my deps recently though. I saw and tried a few other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904403/unable-to-find-any-graphql-type-definitions-for-the-following-pointers-src) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218757/graphql-codegen-not-running-with-config-file) but to no avail :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same issue recently. And I change the codegen.yml to solve this issue.
You can try to modify your codegen.yml like this:
My API is written with TypeScript/Apollo and I am able to run queries/mutations on http://localhost:4000/graphql. My front-end is with Next.js and Apollo client. I use GraphQL Codegenerator to generate the client-side code I need.

I am using:

```
"@graphql-codegen/cli": "1.20.1",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript": "1.20.2",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "1.17.14",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "2.2.1",
```

and my codegen.yml file is:

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
documents: "src/graphql/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
The script I run when I change my API resolvers is "gen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"
```

If I do run this code, I get the error:

```
  ✖ src/generated/graphql.tsx
    Error: 
          Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers:
        
              - src/graphql/**/*.graphql
but If set my codegen.yml file as follows it works (and I tested a query in one of the component, I can access data):

overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
documents:
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RecipeSnippet.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RegularError.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RegularUser.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/fragments/RegularUserResponse.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/createRecipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/deleteRecipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/login.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/logout.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/register.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/mutations/updateRecipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/queries/me.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/queries/recipe.graphql"
  - "src/graphql/queries/recipes.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I ended up deleting the project from my computer, pulling it again from the repo, yarn install and yarn gen. And it worked. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `documents: "src/graphql/**/*.graphql"` by

```
documents: "src/graphql/**/*.{gql,graphql}"
```

The path of my schema was : src/graphql/Queries/GetCustomers.query.gql

I'm using :

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.7.2",
"@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.16.1",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript": "2.8.5",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.5.10",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.3.7",
```

Comment: How is this materially different from the accepted answer?